# Importing owner information from a public database

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import owner name and address from the following website

`https://qpublic.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=835&LayerID=15172&PageTypeID=4&PageID=6829&Q=1214548789&KeyValue=33-2S-21-42195-00A-A101`

I tried

`=importxml("https://qpublic.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=835&LayerID=15172&PageTypeID=4&PageID=6829&Q=1214548789&KeyValue=33-2S-21-42195-00A-A101", "//a")`

but that did not work. I was able to import sales data using

`=IMPORTHTML("https://qpublic.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=835&LayerID=15172&PageTypeID=4&PageID=6829&Q=1214548789&KeyValue=33-2S-21-42195-00A-A101","table",4)`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=IMPORTXML(
    "https://qpublic.schneidercorp.com/Application.aspx?AppID=835&LayerID=15172&PageTypeID=4&PageID=6829&Q=1214548789&KeyValue=33-2S-21-42195-00A-A101",
    "//section//div[@class='four-column-blocks']/*[position()>1]/text()"
)
```

This gives data in three cells:

1. Owners
2. Street
3. City